# jquery click navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I am trying to make my navigation a click dropdown for "Loose Leaf Tea". Its sort of working now but when i click any other link in the navigation the dropdown is still coming down. Can someone please help me out with this? Thanks!

```
 <div id="ta-navcontainer">

 <div class="click-nav">
<ul id="ta-nav">
<li class="gifts"><a href="/category_s/1831.htm" title="Coming Soon"><img src="http://www.teaamore.com/v/vspfiles/assets/nav-imgs/ta-gifts.png" alt="Gifts" width="26" height="32">Gifts</a>
</li>
<li class="edibles"> <a href="/category_s/1847.htm"><img src="http://www.teaamore.com/v/vspfiles/assets/nav-imgs/edibles.png" alt="Tea Ware" width="41" height="32">Edibles</a>
</li>
<li class="teaware"> <a href="/category_s/1823.htm"><img src="http://www.teaamore.com/v/vspfiles/assets/nav-imgs/ta-tea-ware.png" alt="Tea Ware" width="34" height="32">Tea Ware</a>
</li>
<li class="single-orgins"> <a href="/category_s/1849.htm"><img src="http://www.teaamore.com/v/vspfiles/assets/nav-imgs/single-orgin-tea.png" alt="Single Origin Tea" width="32" height="32">Single Origin Tea</a>
</li>
<li class="loose-leaf"> <a class="clicker"><img src="http://www.teaamore.com/v/vspfiles/assets/nav-imgs/loose-leaf-tea.png" alt="Tea Ware" width="34" height="32">Loose Leaf Tea</a>
    <ul class="no-js">
        <li class="black-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1822.htm" id="current">Black</a>
        </li>
        <li class="chai-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1827.htm">Chai</a>
        </li>
        <li class="pu-era-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1838.htm">Pu-erh</a>
        </li>
        <li class="oolong-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1829.htm">Oolong</a>
        </li>
        <li class="green-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1825.htm">Green</a>
        </li>
        <li class="white-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1826.htm">White</a>
        </li>
        <li class="rooibos-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1828.htm">Rooibos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tisanes-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1839.htm">Tisanes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="yerba-mate-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1843.htm">Yerba Mate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="wellness-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1845.htm">Wellness</a>
        </li>
        <li class="iced-tea"><a href="http://www.teaamore.com/category_s/1841.htm">Iced Tea</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="sachet-bag"> <a href="/category_s/1848.htm" title="Coming Soon"><img src="http://www.teaamore.com/v/vspfiles/assets/nav-imgs/tea-bag-sachet.png" alt="Sachet Tea" width="32" height="32">Sachet Tea</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

```
    <script>

 $(function () {
$('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
$('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
$('.click-nav .js').click(function(e) {
    $('.click-nav .js ul').slideToggle(200);
    //$('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.click-nav .js ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.click-nav .js ul', this).slideUp();
        $('.clicker').removeClass('active');
    }

     });

 });

 </script>
```

Comment: You need to use `this` within your jQuery element declaration. If you creaate a fiddle i will show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and comment your `$(document).click(function() {` block

```
$('.click-nav > ul').toggleClass('no-js js');
$('.click-nav .js ul').hide();
$('.click-nav li').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(200);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

or you want something another?

Comment: This worked the best with my current code! Thanks so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like this?

```
$(function () {
    $('.click-nav .no-js').hide();

    $('.clicker').click(function() {
       ($('.no-js').toggle())

    });
});
```

Here's a jfiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/c3sQr/

Answer (score 0):

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/2tSLx/3/) and is much simpler, shorter, and less fragile:

```
$(function () {
  var onClickLink = function( event ) {
    $li = $( event.target ).closest( 'li' );

    if ( $li.hasClass( 'loose-leaf' ) ) {
      $li.find( 'ul' ).slideToggle(200);
      return false;
    }

    $( '#ta-nav' ).slideUp();
    return true;
  };

  $( 'ul#ta-nav > li.loose-leaf > ul' ).hide();
  $( 'ul#ta-nav > li' ).on( 'click', onClickLink );
});
```

I also added a little CSS to make the loose-leaf tea link stand out; we should really put a down arrow next to it, and have it underlined as well :)  It looks like this:

```
cursor : pointer; color : green
```